# perl foreach looping arrays, simple question

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, for-loop

Really simple perl question, but confusing me greatly.

```
foreach $val (@{$obj->something()}) {
    # this works
}

@array = $obj->something();
foreach $val (@array) {
    # this does not
}
```

What do i need to do to make the second work (i.e: assign the array seperately), i've used the first form a fair bit but dont really understand what it does differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably:

```
@array = @{$obj->something()};
```

From the first example, it looks like `$obj->something()` returns an array reference, you'll need to dereference it.

Also, you should really `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, and declare your variables like

```
my @array = @{$obj->something()};
foreach my $val (@array) {
    # this does not
}
```

This will make it much easier to find mistakes (although probably not this one), even in a three line script.